# 2d array in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm learning how to use arrays in Haskell, for example, generating a times table:

```
Prelude Data.Array> array ((0,0),(10,12)) [((x,y),x*y) | x<-[0..10], y<-[0..12]] 
array ((0,0),(10,12)) [((0,0),0),((0,1),0),((0,2),0),((0,3),0),((0,4),0),((0,5),0),((0,6),0),((0,7),0),((0,8),0),((0,9),0),((0,10),0),((0,11),0),((0,12),0),((1,0),0),((1,1),1),((1,2),2),((1,3),3),((1,4),4),((1,5),5),((1,6),6),((1,7),7),((1,8),8),((1,9),9),((1,10),10),((1,11),11),((1,12),12),((2,0),0),((2,1),2),((2,2),4),((2,3),6),((2,4),8),((2,5),10),((2,6),12),((2,7),14),((2,8),16),((2,9),18),((2,10),20),((2,11),22),((2,12),24),((3,0),0),((3,1),3),((3,2),6),((3,3),9),((3,4),12),((3,5),15),((3,6),18),((3,7),21),((3,8),24),((3,9),27),((3,10),30),((3,11),33),((3,12),36),((4,0),0),((4,1),4),((4,2),8),((4,3),12),((4,4),16),((4,5),20),((4,6),24),((4,7),28),((4,8),32),((4,9),36),((4,10),40),((4,11),44),((4,12),48),((5,0),0),((5,1),5),((5,2),10),((5,3),15),((5,4),20),((5,5),25),((5,6),30),((5,7),35),((5,8),40),((5,9),45),((5,10),50),((5,11),55),((5,12),60),((6,0),0),((6,1),6),((6,2),12),((6,3),18),((6,4),24),((6,5),30),((6,6),36),((6,7),42),((6,8),48),((6,9),54),((6,10),60),((6,11),66),((6,12),72),((7,0),0),((7,1),7),((7,2),14),((7,3),21),((7,4),28),((7,5),35),((7,6),42),((7,7),49),((7,8),56),((7,9),63),((7,10),70),((7,11),77),((7,12),84),((8,0),0),((8,1),8),((8,2),16),((8,3),24),((8,4),32),((8,5),40),((8,6),48),((8,7),56),((8,8),64),((8,9),72),((8,10),80),((8,11),88),((8,12),96),((9,0),0),((9,1),9),((9,2),18),((9,3),27),((9,4),36),((9,5),45),((9,6),54),((9,7),63),((9,8),72),((9,9),81),((9,10),90),((9,11),99),((9,12),108),((10,0),0),((10,1),10),((10,2),20),((10,3),30),((10,4),40),((10,5),50),((10,6),60),((10,7),70),((10,8),80),((10,9),90),((10,10),100),((10,11),110),((10,12),120)]
```

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to hold a matrix or 2d-array of values? Why does it give a list of ((x,y),value) instead of giving a table of values? Is there a way to change how it prints the array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a tuple as the index is the correct way of getting a multidimensional array. If you want to print it out differently, you'll have to write your own function to convert it to a string.

For example, you could have something like this:

```
showTable arr = 
  unlines $ map (unwords . map (show . (arr !))) indices
  where indices = [[(x, y) | x <- [startX..endX]] | y <- [startY..endY]]
        ((startX, startY), (endX, endY)) = bounds arr
```

Comment: `indices = range $ bounds arr` would work too, by the way (and avoid the shadowing of `length`, plus it'd also work on arrays of every index type).

Comment: unfortunately it is missing the last row and last column.

Comment: @ehird: Wait, never mind. The way I did it, I need the indices in a nested list by row.

Comment: A more robust version would take the lower bounds into account as well, instead of hard-coding them at zero.

Answer (score 3):

That's just the `Show` instance. The `Array` constructor is not exported from `Data.Array`, so you can't directly construct an array. The `Show` instance produces valid Haskell code that can be used to construct the array from the list of its associations.